# GPS Location from the mobile browser in ASP.NET/C#?

Tags: asp.net, gps

I want to develop a web application using ASP.NET/C# that stores gps location of the user.

What I want is to build a mobile application that access GPS hardware of different plateforms(iPhone, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phones,...)

Is it possible.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [Geolocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API). It's an HTML5 standard and iPhones and Android browsers both support it, as do modern desktop browsers. You would call this API from Javascript on the client, then pass values to the server using, for example, hidden form fields, or the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hardware, yes. There are many plugins available to allow you to develop against C# for the different platforms. For example for Andriod there is a package called [MONO](http://android.xamarin.com/)  that has libraries so that you can develop in C#. There are about three different packages for BlackBerry (all unsupported). I'm not aware of anything for iPhone but they probably exist.

You just need to do a little research

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the hardware, yes.  There are many plugins available to allow you to develop against C# for the different platforms.  For example for Andriod there is a package called MONO (http://android.xamarin.com/)that has libraries so that you can develop in C#.  There are about three different packages for BlackBerry (all unsupported).  I'm not aware of anything for iPhone but they probably exist.
You just need to do a little research.